# How to use react.usecallback in useeffect return statement using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to use useCallback method in useEffect return statement.

below is how i use useCallback method on clicking a button.

```
 function SectionTabListComponent() {
     const handleExitClick = React.useCallback(() => {
         stopEditing();
         onClose();
    }, [stopEditing, onClose]);
    return (
        <button onClick={handleExitClick}/>
    );
 }
```

now i want to call handleExitClick method in componentunmount using useeffect instead of on clicking button

i tried something like below,

```
function SectionTabListComponent(){
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleExitClick = React.useCallback(() => {
            stopEditing();
            onClose();
        }, [stopEditing, onClose]);
        return () => {
            handleExitClick();
        };
   },[]);
```

}

but gives error react.useCallback() cannot be called inside a callback.React hooks must be called within a function component or custom react hook.

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to clean up your **handleExitClick** in useEffect?

Comment: this parent component is  a list component that renders on clicking  a section tab. when user clicks on another section tab then it should execute the saveEditing and onClose methods before component unmounts.

Comment: Why do you want to nest inside parent function ?

Comment: i have edited my question Parent here in this example is actually SectionTabListComponent.

Comment: can you add barebone of what you want in codesandbox[https://codesandbox.io/]?

Comment: Why not call useEffect directly at component level ? why call it in lifeCycle ?

Comment: there is no `componentunmount` .  what do u mean? `componentWillUnmount` ? and forget lifecycle in react hook